# Connection with Interface Builder, but UITableView is nil?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a little strange problem, that i am unable to reload a UITableView in a Popover. I have a function which i call from my parent View Controller but it always crashes with the error `... found a nil value` - but how can be my UITableView be nil?

[image: Connection IB]

So with this code shown in my screenshot i'll always get "its nil" in my console. But why?

Comment: Does the table log out as nil in viewWillAppear as well? It could be that since it's an IBOutlet the view hasn't been set up yet, so the table is technically nil in viewDidLoad (or wherever your code is)

Comment: Hmm i think the Problem is that i want to reload the Table when its not visible (its in a Popover, and i want to reload the data when the view is not visible) - in viewWillLoad the tableView is not nil (so when i click on my Popover)

Comment: In viewWillAppear the view isn't visible yet, so if you reload your data there then it should work. I would try moving the call to reload the table to viewWillAppear to see if that solves the issue or not

Comment: Ok ive checked that and that is really the problem. I am unable to reload a TableView in a Popover, i need to reload it after it appears (that was little weird to me, that my Outlet is not working while it is not visible). Set this as answer and i will mark it as accepted. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In viewWillAppear the view isn't visible yet, so if you reload your data there then it should work. I would try moving the call to reload the table to viewWillAppear to see if that solves the issue or not

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It's have to be Files owner, don't why it's showing File download handler view controller. make it fileowner, it will work

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but ill found already the problem. The Outlet is not activ when the Popover is not visible. That is something new to me.